# Error module github.com/golang/protobuf is deprecated

Tags: go, protobuf-go

I have a problem with the command line `go get` or `go get .` in my Golang project. The error is

```
go: module github.com/golang/protobuf is deprecated: Use the "google.golang.org/protobuf" module instead.
```

I have tried step by step install package protobuf in this website [enter link description here](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/go/quickstart/)

but I can't resolve my problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can check your code if you import `github.com/golang/protobuf` somewhere.

If you don't use the import in your code, check which dependency imports it:

```
go mod graph | grep github.com/golang/protobuf
```

or

```
go mod why github.com/golang/protobuf
```

Basically you need to eliminate that import somehow either by removing it in your code, updating your dependencies or maybe even eliminate the dependency that hasn't updated to the new `protobuf` package yet. (Had to do that recently by kicking `etcd` which I used for election)

Comment: `go mod why github.com/golang/protobuf` will show the full chain importing the package back to the direct dependency.

Comment: Good point! Note that at least until recently `go mod why` did not always work for all dependencies. Example: https://forum.golangbridge.org/t/go-mod-has-not-need-package/17082